# @click in vue component is not fired

Tags: vue.js

I'm struggling with vue event listner.
I can fire the mounted() method.
But I can't fire the on click method.

this is my vue component.
Could you help me??

Layout.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="layout">
        <div class="button">
            <button @click="update">update1</button>
            <button @click.native="update">update2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        alert("") //fired
    },
    methods: {
      update() {
        alert("") //not fired both of the buttons
      },
    },
}
</script>
```

======additional information=============

app.js

```
Vue.component('vue-layout', require('./views/Layout.vue').default);
```

html

```
<body>
      <div id="app">
            <vue-layout></vue-layout>
      </div>

      <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: it seems work, i tested it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/znmrj741px)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim thank you for testing.I compare your code with my code, there were some differences...(I edited my post).Can you tell me what is my code's problem?? Any way I corrected it just like your code, and now click event gets fired. thanks.

Comment: your code seems fine just remove `.native` modifier